# Loop connection query and place the var[i] inside response with promise or other

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to place var[i] ( scoreAvis[i] inside the response to make another SQL query but the console.log say undefined or give me the last result of my var[i]

obj looks like this:

```js
var scoreAvis = [
 {
  "caracname": "carac1",
  "score": 4
 },
 {
  "caracname": "carac2",
  "score": 5
 },
 {
  "caracname": "carac3",
  "score": 3
 }
]
```

```js
for (i = 0; i < scoreAvis.length; i++) {
 if (scoreAvis[i].score > 0){
  connection.query("SELECT AVG(" + scoreAvis[i].caracname + ") FROM avis WHERE products_id=1", function (error, results, fields) {
   if (!!error) {
    console.log(error)
   } else {
    console.log(scoreAvis[i].caracname + " yes you get the data ! you can do another query connection with it")
   }
  });
 };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an array you probably should not use a loop with callback that takes your disposable index `i` from closure. By the time your callback is called the `i` value is the length of the array. You can use `map` instead.

```
const queryAsPromise = connection => args =>
  new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>
      connection.query.apply(
        connection,
        args.concat([
          (error, results, fields) =>
            (!!error)
              ? reject(error)
              : resolve([results,fields])
        ])
      )
  );

Promise.all(
  scoreAvis.filter(av=>av.score>1)//only where score > 1
  .map(//map to a promise
    av=>
      queryAsPromise(
        connection
      )([
        //https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers
        `SELECT AVG(${connection.escapeId(av.carcname)}) FROM avis WHERE products_id=1`
      ])
      .then(
        result=> {
          console.log(
            "query result:",result,"from:",
            av,
            " yes you get the data ! you can do another query connection with it"
          );
          return result;
        }
      )
  )
).then(
  results=>
    console.log("Got all results:",results)
).catch(
  err=>console.error("Something went wrong:",err)
);
```