# SQL query function when for loop is terminated

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have loop like

```
for (i=0, i < var.lenght , i++ )
```

and I would like to execute a sql query when the loop is terminated, how to do that? I trien promise then but it didn't work

Comment: can you check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for better understanding.

Comment: If you want to execute something after the loop finished ... simply put it after the loop?

Comment: you could try doing the query after the `}` of the for loop

Comment: Is this going to be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48507937/1641941) question again? The answer is quite clear I think. Just place your query in the last `then`

Comment: @hmr you don't tell me how to launch function while loop for is totally finished

Comment: I just did (again), you look at the code in the example it says `"Got all results:",results` assuming you'd guess that's where all queries are finished. It also states you should avoid the loop because you have an array you can map over.

Comment: You could use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48507937/edit) link in your original question and update it with the code you are currently using. Add the problem you are having, any errors or output that you did not expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
for (i=0, i < var.lenght , i++ ) {
    something in the loop
}

Then put your query here;
```

Comment: That won't work, See comment under the question. Kevin is doing asynchronous work in the loop and uses a closure of `i` but since the code is asynchronous by the time the callback within the loop is called the value of `i` is the length of the array. That question was already answered by advising to use `map`  and `Promise.all` Kevin just posted his previous question again but in such a bad way that it's totally unclear what the actual problem was.